# Unable to access desktop file from a macOS app

Tags: macos, permissions, desktop, appstore-sandbox, entitlements

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have a simple snippet of code :

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/myuser/Desktop/test.csv" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
```

which when I run I get the error :

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “test.csv” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/myuser/Desktop/test.csv, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002388fc0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
```

I am adding this snippet of code in an existing app which has a Application Sandbox section. If I take this same snippet and put in a brand new app, then it works fine but the new app does not have a App Sandbox section. What am I missing here? How do I ask for permission to access the Desktop folder?

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question, but did you set the File Access Type in your App Sandbox to Read/Write?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was sandbox. I had application sandbox enabled. When I reoved that everything works as expected.